# Multiple definition error for a class function

Tags: c++, class, makefile

I'm working on a program to test whether a user-entered string is a palindrome or not using stacks and queues. This is just a test to make sure my function is passing correctly. I keep this multiple definition error though. I've tried renaming my variables and my function but the same error keeps occurring.

Makefile created by compiler:

```
# Project: P5
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = main.o Palindrome.o
LINKOBJ  = main.o Palindrome.o
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
BIN      = P5.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)

Palindrome.o: Palindrome.c
    $(CPP) -c Palindrome.c -o Palindrome.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Error messages:

```
C:\Users\me\Downloads\school\CSC\260\Palindrome.o   Palindrome.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `TestPal::isPalindrome(std::string)'
C:\Users\me\Downloads\school\CSC\260\main.o main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
C:\Users\me\Downloads\school\CSC\260\Palindrome.o   Palindrome.c:(.text+0x2e): multiple definition of `TestPal::TestPal()'
C:\Users\me\Downloads\school\CSC\260\main.o main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): first defined here
C:\Users\me\Downloads\school\CSC\260\Palindrome.o   Palindrome.c:(.text+0x2e): multiple definition of `TestPal::TestPal()'
C:\Users\me\Downloads\school\CSC\260\main.o main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): first defined here
C:\Users\me\Downloads\school\CSC\260\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
25      C:\Users\me\Downloads\school\CSC\260\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'P5.exe' failed
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack"
#include "queue"
#include "Palindrome.c"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Pal;
    cout << "Enter a palindrome: ";
    getline (cin, Pal);

    TestPal test;
    test.isPalindrome(Pal);


    return 0;
}
```

Palindrome.h

```
#ifndef PALINDROME_H
#define PALINDROME_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class TestPal
{
    public: 
        bool isPalindrome(string);
        TestPal();

};

#endif
```

Palindrome.c

```
#include "Palindrome.h"
#include "stack"
#include "queue"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool TestPal::isPalindrome(string Pal)
{

    cout << Pal;
    return false;
};

TestPal::TestPal()
{

};
```

Comment: Palindrome.c containing C++ code is a bit jarring. Recommend renaming the sucker to Palindrome.cpp to prevent confusion.

Comment: In addition to what's said above, some compilers use the file extension to determine how to compile the code, so `.cpp` is conventional and `.c` may kick it into C mode, which will cause errors.

Comment: Yeah my professor told us to label it that way when we turn it in. I thought it was pretty strange when I saw it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `#include "Palindrome.c"` is the problem, you're importing the implementation which is a huge problem as far as compilation goes.

This should be:

```
#include "Palindrome.h"
```

Unless you're doing something really strange, never include `.c` files. Stick to `.h` (or `.hpp` if you prefer) only.